# Thunderbolt 2 to Display Port

Tags: thunderbolt, displayport

I received a 2015 MacBook Pro with two Thunderbolt 2 ports. Can I use a [Mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013PWQPFS)?

According to Apple:

> Thunderbolt and Thunderbolt 2 are not the same as Mini DisplayPort . They have the same shape, but use different symbols on the cable and port. However, this port does support Mini DisplayPort for video output, so you can use a Mini DisplayPort cable to connect a Mini DisplayPort display.

It seems you can, but I have had trouble with Mac-related compatibility before, so I want to make sure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to use this with a DisplayPort compatible monitor:

- Yes you can. As you quote:

> However, [Thunderbolt 2] does support Mini DisplayPort for video output

This is definitely correct and I can confirm that this works on a similar machine. The cable you show should work as intended.

---

What doesn't work is using a Mini DisplayPort as Thunderbolt 2, e.g. for transferring data to a hard drive. But you want to use Thunderbolt 2 as a video output, which is one of the intended use-cases of TB2, similar to the newer TB3, USB-3 and USB 4 (which in theory equals TB 3) connectors.